# Where to declare a exception (Spring Java)

Tags: java, spring, exception

I have 3 projects:

1. `helloWbService`
2. `helloService`
3. `helloDao`

---

Where do I declare the custom exception in the 3 project(duplicate class) or in another project helloeEception?

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to you could make a new project write it there, build a jar file and import it into each project. 
Might be useful if you intend writing more custom exceptions in the future.

But if it's a one off, I'd probably just implement it in the three projects.